# Cannot display a result based on a database id when id is passed to view

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, mamp

```
<table class="table">

<tr>
    <th>Name</th>

</tr>

<tr th:each="recipe : ${recipes}">
    <td th:text="${recipe.Name}"></td>
    <td>
            <span th:each="recipe,iterStat : ${recipes}">

            </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{/recipe/food/{id}(id=${recipe.id})}">view</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to click this link above, utilizing this controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="recipe/food/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String viewRecipe(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("name", recipeDao.findOne(id));
    model.addAttribute("recipeText", recipeDao.findOne(id));
    return "Recipes/food" ;
}
```

to display a single item, based on  its id here

```
<table class="table">

<tr>
    <th>Name</th>

</tr>
<form method ="post" th:action="recipe/food/{id}" th:object=${recipe}">
<tr th:each="recipe : ${recipes}">

    <td th:text="${recipe.name}">text</td>
    <td th:text="${recipe.recipeText}">text</td>
</tr>

<span th:errors="*{recipeText}" class="error"></span>
</form>
```

however i only get a 404, but the url information is correct

Comment: can you post your directory structure for the view files?

Comment: @shakhawat resources/templates/Recipes/food, Recipes/index displays a list that i have setup just fine as well.

Comment: do you have any view resolver added?

Comment: can you add a debug pointer / msg on the post handler to check if the post action went through. If it can post successfully, then the problem is about view and view resolver.

Comment: You may also need to move `resources/templates/Recipes/food` to `Recipes/food` just like `index` page.

Comment: i'm not sure how to view the post handler in the debugger specifically, and the Recipes/index is in the same directory structure as the aforementioned Recipes/food structure, and works fine. just didn't type it all out sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the link it will execute a GET-request, so try changing the method in the Controller to method = RequestMethod.GET or simply remove method = RequestMethod.POST.

**Update:**

The part of the food template that is in the third code snippet is looping over a list named recipes, but the Controller method isn't adding a list as an attribute to the model only "name" and "recipeText". What you want is probably the template to display the recipe that you clicked the link for? Something like `<h4 th:text="${name}"></h4> <span th:text="${recipeText}" />`

Comment: unfortunately this didn't appear to change anything.

Comment: ok, and you don't have any RequestMapping at class-level in your controller so that the url don't match? Have you had a look at the request in the network-tab in your browser to see that the request that goes away is what you expect it to be?

Comment: i do have @RequestMapping("recipe") above my public class RecipeController

Comment: it looks as if the controller isn't actually returning the food.html to the browser, and thus not passing along the id etc

Comment: If you have @RequestMapping both on the class and method the actual path of the endpoint is the concat of those two, so in your case it is "recipe/recipe/food/{id}", so probably that's why you get a 404 eaven though you changed to GET.

Comment: alright so i've changed the class mapping, and now my bootstrap template page is displayed with the navigation, but it still doesn't display information. in the networks inspector my "Add" html shows up when i go to it, but the "food" template does not.Also, the template that is generated, that is displayed is a number, what i should be passing as the id.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean now, is the third code snippet in your post from the food template? Do you mean that the id isn't passed to the Controller method as it should?

Comment: ah okay sorry for the confusion. so the id is definitely passed to the controller, i can see the id in the url in the browser when i click the link it’s passed to, but it looks as if nothing is passed to the food template which is the third code snippet

Comment: The part of the food template that is in the code snippet is looping over a list named recipes, but the Controller method isn't adding a list as an attribute to the model only "name" and "recipeText". Shouldn't the food template display the recipe that you clicked the link for? Something like <h4 th:text="${name}"></h4> <span th:text="${recipeText}" />

Comment: i think you’re right there. i’ll give it a try here in a bit, but i may need to try something else entirely haha seems like too much time spent on something so silly. thanks so much for all your help though! @nordenvall